# combine two T-SQL in a dynamic way

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

How can I using something like if or case..when to combine the following code into one?

```
if @para = 'test'
begin
select * from Table A where status='A' and id in (select id from Table B)
end
else if @para = 'others'
begin
select * from Table A where status='A' and id in (select id from Table c)
end
```

like select * from Table A where id in if @para = XXX then (select id from Table B)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you elaborate little more, are you looking for a case based query ?

Comment: yes exactly! I wanna combine two sql into one. Can I do that? @ArunprasanthKV

Comment: actually this is a subquery...sth like select * from table where col1 = xxx and col2=xxx and id in (................)..so if i use case when ..error msg will be prompt that subqueries cant do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * 
from Table A 
where (id in (select id from Table B) and @para = 'test')
      OR
      (id in (select id from Table c) and @para = 'others')
```

Answer (score 1):

As you tagged stored procedure i made it as one ... try it like this

```
create procedure GetData (@para nvarchar(100))
as 
begin

declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @sql = case 
            when @para = 'test'
        then 
            'Select * from TableA A
                join TableB B on A.id = B.ID'
       else -- if @para = 'others' goes into else
            'Select * from TableA A
                join TableB B on A.id = B.ID'
        end

execute (@sql)
end
```